# Regex to ignore matches on nested delimeters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have an input string as follows:

```
var format = "{0}({1:2}({*:8})){2:3}({3:16})";
```

**For the "what are you doing this for" questions**:
What the above format is telling us is much like the `string.Format(string, args)` method with some modifications.

- {0} is an insert index
- {1:2} is an insert index with specified length in bytes
- ({3:16}) is a grouped insert index which retains a copy of the matching sequence

Expected graph of output:

- {0}
- ({1:2}({*:8}))
- {2:3}
- ({3:16})

What I'm getting now:

- {0}
- ({1:2}
- ({*:8}))
- {2:3}
- ({3:16})

The regular expression I'm working with now:

```
var regExpr = @"\(?\{\(*([^/}]+)\)*\}\)?";
```

As an aside, since I am just now learning `RegEx` I expect comments about the efficiency of the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I think I've found a solution - this is probably a horribly inefficient pattern to match, but I was intrigued as to whether it could be done at all:

```
(((?<r>\{)|(?<-r>\})|(?<b>\()|(?<-b>\))|[^{}()]))+?(?(r)(?!))(?(b)(?!))
```

[Working On RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=5b4424b9-d81b-4083-a905-506dc9a1a6ec) (The .NET Regex Tester) [Also tested here](http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx)

**Explanation**:

First we have `(?<r>\{)|(?<-r>\})|(?<b>\()|(?<-b>\)`

These are balancing groups. For every `{` found it adds the match to the `r` group, then for every `}` it removes that match from the `r` group. The same is done for `(` and `)` in the `b` group.

Then the final part of the alternation is `[^{}()]` which matches everything else - i.e. anything that might appear between the brackets.

Finally we have `(?(r)(?!))(?(b)(?!))` (you may be able to use `(?(r|b)(?!))` but it screwed up the results on 1 of the 2 testers I used). This is an `if..then` construct, it checks if there is anything in the `r` or `b` groups, if there is then `(?!)` - a negative lookahead for nothing, which always returns false. This makes the match return false if the brackets don't balance.

Since the `+` after the alternation is a lazy `+?` it'll match the shortest segments that keep the brackets balanced.

Which, on RegexHero at least, matches:

```
\1 {0}
\2 ({1:2}({*:8}))
\3 {2:3}
\4 ({3:16})
```

Comment: Can't guarantee this works on C#, RegexHero is the closest thing I have to test on.

Comment: I was afraid this would get somewhat complicated. Thanks and this seems to do what I need.

Answer (score 1):

This is generally not possible using regular expressions, but read about [Balancing Group Definition](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2005/03/15/396452.aspx) extension in .NET.

Comment: [really?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813751/get-inner-patterns-recursively-using-regex-c-sharp) - I'm not trying to be a smartarse, I don't use .net, does that answer not suggest otherwise though?

Comment: @OGHaza see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133601/can-regular-expressions-be-used-to-match-nested-patterns)

Comment: Well, I'm not trying to immediately match on a nested 'grouping'. I only want the outer match.

Comment: And I'm not really following what the article is conveying on balanced group definitions.

Comment: @KonradKokosa, if you read further answers on that question it suggests .NET is one of a number of regex engines that are capable of such tasks.